# How to map an index range in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
<table>
   <tbody>
   {this.state.data.map((person, i) => <TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />)}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

This maps my entire array, but how would I map from a minimum index to a maximum index? So say my array has 500 elements. I want to map this array (of data) from index 15 to 24 inclusive. (So I'd only have 10 elements on my screen).

edit: these answers are interesting.. but no mention of .filter() though? I saw that it might help what I want but I'm trying to figure out how to do it in react.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`Array#slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to extract a shallow copy of the values you want from `this.state.data`.

```
const SubsetTable = props => {
  let {startIndex, endIndex, data} = props

  let subset = data.slice(startIndex, endIndex)

  return (
   <table>
     <tbody>
       {subset.map((person, i) => (<TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />)}
     </tbody>
   </table>
  )
}

// Since splice() is inclusive of the range given, you'll need to 
// adjust your range to include that last index if needed
// The below will grab all values in indexes 15-24, 
<SubsetTable startIndex={15} endIndex={25} data={this.state.data} />
```

Since you've updated your question, regarding use of [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), `filter()` requires that you iterate over the entire set. `Array#slice()` is only going to extract the contiguous index range that you'd like extract. `filter()` is better when you gave a condition that you want all your Array data members to meet and and your collection is unordered.

Comment: 15 to 24 **inclusive**. Remember, `Array.prototype.slice` goes up to, but not including the last index. `data.slice(startIndex, endIndex + 1)` :)

Answer (score 4):

However you set the min/max (let's assume state)

```
this.state = {
    min: 15,
    max: 24,
};
```

You just adjust your map to an if statement to return if the index (`i`) is greater than or equal to the min, and less than or equal to the max.

```
{this.state.data.map((person, i) => {
    if (i >= this.state.min && i <= this.state.max) {
        return (<TableRow key = {i} data = {person} />);
    }
})}
```

Now, we can be real here and say this is inefficient. So, after you have reached the max, break out of the loop, which may require a different loop type since I think you can't break from a `map`

Comment: not sure what it will affect, but this method will return array with undefined values at indexes <15 and >24.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava was just typing that myself. Pretty sure React would prefer those values to be `null` instead.

Comment: @peteb Yes, I agree I don't know how react will react to that. otherwise it is also not a very bad solution.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I didn't even think about that, I think if we want efficiency here, a simple `for` loop will work best because it will retain O(n) notation while being able to break out once it reaches the max.

Comment: @Sagivb.g why so? You can use `break` in a for loop and it's the most efficient loop. Correct me if I'm wrong but `slice`ing will give the complexity a nested boost (don't get me wrong, it does look prettier)

Comment: how can you return a `jsx` from a `for` loop? I never suggested `slice` by the way.

Comment: @Sagivb.g You don't have to return it, before return statement in render, you push JSX elements in a variable (say in for loop) and render that variable then. (I will upvote this answer for its simplicity ;) though not sure how undefined values will affect things :)).

Comment: ok, that's sounds more like my answer but i did it inside a `reduce`. feels more functional to me :)

Comment: @Sagivb.g Yeap a simple for loop could also do the trick :). your answer is also interesting though the for loop approach is the simplest IMHO. :)

Comment: @Sagivb.g it seems I am less into functional prog. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) must return the exact same length of the array.
So you need to do some filtering and mapping again.

To minimize the number of loops and iterations, i would use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which will let you do both filtering and mapping in the same iteration.

Running example:

```js
const persons = [
  { value: 'John', id: 1 },
  { value: 'Jane', id: 2 },
  { value: 'Mike', id: 3 },
  { value: 'Nikol', id: 4 },
  { value: 'Bob', id: 5 },
  { value: 'Dave', id: 6 },
]

const TableRow = ({ data }) => <tr><td>{data.value}</td></tr>

const start = 2;
const end = 4;

const App = () => (
  <div >
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {
          persons.reduce((result, current, i) => {
            if (i >= start && i <= end) { // 0 based don't forget!
              const row = (<TableRow key={i} data={current} />);
              result.push(row);
            }
            return result;
          }, [])
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: A consideration when comparing `slice()` and `reduce()`; `reduce()` will be slower than `slice()` for larger sets when you have a small range that you're extracting. Its cheaper to grab only the items needed and then iterate over that smaller set using `map()`. Instead, `reduce()` will always need to iterate over all elements within the set even if that element isn't in the range. The performance gain for `reduce()` is when you know you need to reduce an entire set of items and perform an operation against items within the reduced set.

Comment: Abusing reduce to handle all the logic at once is much less readable (and not provably faster, with inlining) than some of the other answers. There is nothing functional about `push`ing from a reduce, that is a horrible smell. This is just a for loop by another name, not a meaningful reduce.